# Changing pandas DataFrame values based on values from the same and previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas df:
[image: pandas df]
it is sorted by 'patient_id', 'StartTime', 'hour_counter'.

I'm looking to perform two conditional operations on the df:

1. Change the value of the `Delta_Value` column
2. Delete the entire row
   Where the condition depends on the values of `ParameterID` or `patient_id` in the current row and the row before.

I managed to do that using classic programming (i.e. a simple loop in Python), but not using Pandas.

Specifically, I want to change the 'Delta_Value' to 0 or delete the entire row, if the `ParameterID` in the current row is different from the one at the row before.

I've tried to use `.groupby().first()`, but that won't work in some cases because the same `patient_id` can have multiple occurrences of the same `ParameterID` with a different
`ParameterID` in between those occurrences. For example record 10 in the df.
And I need the records to be sorted by the `StartTime` & `hour_counter`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)